# PsExec -i parameter works only with console

Tags: psexec

I am using PsExec to run a process on a remote computer but I want also to use the -i parameter in order the process interact with the computer desktop.

For example:

```
PsExec.exe \\computer1 -i -h powershell.exe -noexit -command hostname
```

When I RDP to the machine, I cannot see the "GUI" if the powershell, but I do see a new PowerShell process run under processes.

But if I am using the console feature in my virtualization environment (as this is a VM), I can see the PowerShell process pops up.

Tried to search online a "Console" like feature when using RDP to a machine but it seems like the /console argument has been deprecated...

What else can I try?

Comment: Cant you split into two calls, one with -i for processing desktop stuff and another without it to do your console needs?

Comment: Yes but I still will use the -i parameter... I want to use it to show the “GUI” of the process

Comment: Well you can try adding the session id of the active user to the -i parameter. This number can be acquired by running "query user", for example. The complete command would be PsExec.exe \\computer1 -i 2 -h powershell.exe -noexit -command hostname

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to [hawaii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837494/psexec-i-parameter-works-only-with-console/57450417#comment101343625_56837494):
I just need to add the *session id* after the *i* parameter.